# Configure nginx API periodically

Tags: shell, api, nginx

I am really new to nginx API and I never done API configuration as well.
I configured Ngnix as a load balancer in which I need to set weight for my backend server. base on my CPU utilization I decided to set my weight.

The thing is I don't have any issue getting server utilization but I need patch my server weight to nginx via API

Help me how to configure API

Note: I am getting server utilization periodically. to nginx I have to change server weight dynamically. it has to happen atomically.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to modify an Nginx configuration on the fly like this is, unfortunately, a feature that's only available in the commercial Nginx Plus variety. (E.g., [this tutorial](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/dynamic-configuration-api/).)

As far as I'm aware, the only way to reconfigure the vanilla open source Nginx is to modify the configuration files and either do a reload or a reboot of the service.